# Adding HTTP Client with Generics - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have several clients that I want to perform the same behavior and want to use generics to do it.

Unfortunately, I cannot get this to compile.

I get the "Type t must be a reference type in order to reference it as parameter TClient in the generic type or method ...".

I cannot quite get the syntax right.  Looking for suggestions.

```
public static void AddHttpClient<T>(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder, 
        string apiBaseUrl, string apiScope)
    {
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient<T>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(apiBaseUrl);// new Clients.DepartmentClient(apiBaseUrl);
        }
        ).AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
        {
            var handler = sp.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
            .ConfigureHandler(
                authorizedUrls: new[] { apiBaseUrl },
                scopes: new[] { apiScope }
             );
            return handler;
        });
    }
```

Comment: public static void AddHttpClient<T>(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder, 
            string apiBaseUrl, string apiScope) where T : class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
public static void AddHttpClient<T>(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder, 
    string apiBaseUrl, string apiScope) where T : class
```

You are getting the error because AddHttpClient has a class constraint on its generic type parameter so you need to add the same constraint to your method.

Full method:

```
public static void AddHttpClient<T>(WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder, 
    string apiBaseUrl, string apiScope) where T : class
{
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient<T>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(apiBaseUrl);// new Clients.DepartmentClient(apiBaseUrl);
    }
    ).AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
    {
        var handler = sp.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
        .ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { apiBaseUrl },
            scopes: new[] { apiScope }
         );
        return handler;
    });
}
```

You [can read more about type constraints here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5004074)